# Using Routes to load Controller

Tags: routes, htaccess

I love routes, but they appear limited to loading a specific template. What about loading a plugin/controller based on the route instead? Anyway to do this in craft or am I limited to .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed possible.  You'll want to update your route to point to an array with and identify your controller path with the key `action`:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
  return array(
    'pluginname/edit' => array('action' => 'pluginName/editItem'),
  );
}
```

In your plugin controller, you can create any number of variables you need and hand them off to your template as the second argument in the renderTemplate() method:

```
// PluginNameController.php
public function actionEditItem()
{
    // Create any variables you want available in your template
    $variables['variable'] = craft()->request->getSegment(3);       

    $variables['items'] = craft()->pluginName->getAllItems();

    // Load a particular template and with all of the variables you've created
    $this->renderTemplate('pluginname/_edit', $variables);
}
```

Check out the article [How do I setup a route to point to a controller action instead of a template?](http://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-setup-a-route-to-point-to-a-controller-action-instead-of-a-template) on Straight Up Craft for a more in depth discussion that also goes into how to render the template from your control, hand off variables to your template, and reference multiple controllers.

Comment: Ben, this is just what I was looking for. How would I pass in a variable using CpRoutes(). ie. 'pluginname/edit/variable' => array('action' => 'pluginName/editItem'),

Comment: @DavidAaronMcInnis I've updated the answer to give an example of how to create variables for your template in the controller.